# How do I create a powershell script that will give a directory listing of a directory specified by the user?

Tags: powershell, input, directory, user-input

currently learning how to write scripts for the first time, specifically in powershell. I figured this would be a simple exercise, and I know that get-childitem is a good place to start for this script. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time articulating the things I see online in order to use them myself. Could someone show me how to do this and give me a simple breakdown for it? Thank you tons.

Comment: You might start with learning the very basics of Powershell first. [Getting Started with PowerShell](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/GetStartedPowerShell3) or [Windows PowerShell™ 4: TFM](https://www.sapien.com/books_training/Windows-PowerShell-4) are good places to start. It is beyond the scope of SO or any other forum to teach you step by step how to script.

Comment: Maybe `Get-ChildItem -Path $args[1] -Recurse -Directory`? Could you explain more about the output format?

Comment: This will walk you through it. https://windows.tips.net/T002902_Passing_Parameters_to_a_PowerShell_Script.html

Comment: Your question is not tied to ONE coding problem, but to ALL problems there are at once ;) This is too broad and you won't get any other answers than "pls look at this tutotial here". Please pick one thing you want to know to ask on StackOverflow. But you need to add a code snippet of your script you have pieced together so far and need to add a question/desired behaviour and finally the error message you get when trying to do so. Also add a list of things you have tried so far, so that others do not need to do duplicate work. GL&HF with your first project!